Double function reset button, one physical and one by another MCU
I am facing a little problem on a CPB project on a reset function because a need one physical button and one programmable one by an output pin of an Annex MCU. How can I manage the positive signal output from ESP32 with Vcc  ?
The receiver input has an input pullup that has to go low level to reset.


Does this answer your question? Using an N-channel FET as a switch

Yes i have simulate this and it work but i don't have space to put a N channel fet to my pcb how can i make the same with npn transistor



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Use the ESP output as Vcc.
